# Dependence of Force as a function of Distance?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

Why is the strength of a field (i.e. gravitational or electric) inversely correlated to the square of the radius?

It is clear to me why the further you get a way from a field, the field's enacted force decreases. However, this makes me hypothesize that the relationship should be:

$$F ~=~ k/r$$

However, it is in fact:

$$F ~=~ k/r^2$$

Is this related to the fact that the surface area of a sphere is a function of the square of its radius?

An intuitive explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Because Newton said so.

Comment: Your guess that it's related to the fact that the surface area of a sphere is a function of the square of its radius is correct. Not all fields drop off as $1/r^2$, but all fields that conserve flux and which come from point sources will.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22010/10851 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48447/2451 and links therein.