# Why do I always hear remote train horn at night?

Tags: everyday-life, acoustics

This is definitely not an illusion, as many people have the same experience. I have usually lived in places miles away from train stations, which makes it unlikely to hear any train horns during the day. However at night, occasionally train horns can be heard. I hope if any one can explain the physics of this effect, like possibly sound travels faster at low temperature.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but closely related: [How far can one hear sound?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128144/how-far-can-one-hear-sound)

Comment: Maybe you are actually a character in a novel. Do you also sometimes notice [a breeze blowing, or a dog's bark](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/culturebox/2010/06/somewhere_a_dog_barked.html)?

Comment: Maybe it's not a horn. Could you record it? I don't know how far a train can be heard, but it could possible that during the day there is too much noise.

Comment: What country do you live in? There may be a non-physics answer here -- some places don't require horns for level crossings during the day but do at night when visibility is lower. So the horns just may not be sounding or may not sound as loud during the day when they aren't needed.

Comment: Could be related: [Does sound propagate further in freezing weather?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52269/11459)

Comment: It could also be that the train only comes through at night

Comment: @tpg2114 I have heard the horn in both Nanjing China, and Brisbane, Australia.

Comment: It could also be that the ghost train only comes through at night

Comment: this funny little thing called hallucinations might be it... XD

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two things that can be considered: one is trivial - that it is quieter at night so you are more likely to hear the horn.

The second is physics: the speed of sound depends on the square root of temperature, so the refractive index is proportional to $T^{-1/2}$.

At night it is quite possible to get a temperature inversion, such that air near the ground is colder than higher up. This would normally occur in still conditions and I think is more common in winter.

As the refractive index decreases with height it means that sound waves propagating upwards at some angle to the horizontal will be bent back towards the ground. The sound waves at some distance from the source will be more intense than you might expect if the waves propagated isotropically.

The contrast with the daytime situation would be enhanced by a more normal temperature gradient where the refractive index increases with height.

EDIT: For an excellent visualisation of this effect, see [these animations](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/refract/refract.html) produced by Daniel Russell (Penn State)

Comment: +1 This is the better answer and close to what I was typing, you typed faster.

Comment: That's because I've answered it before. This is really a duplicate.

Comment: I do not think that hearing better at night is anything "trivial", because that may imply that the human ear may apply a kind of CFAR (constant false alarm rate) detector. How does it do it?

Comment: maybe also the chance that the train will sound the horn at night

Comment: @user31748 I don't think either. You hear everything louder at rest, in sleep or in meditation. At least that is my experience. It might be because your brain don't have to process visual information, so it can concentrate on audial information. I don't think the real solution is related to physics, but I am much more involved in biology... ;-)

Comment: Nice ans and awesom link.

Comment: Strictly speaking the speed of sounds depends on the _density_ which, at constant pressure, scales with temperature. And the temperature inversion happens because of evaporation - which, in still conditions, gives the focusing effect. And is particularly strong over bodies of water (no surprise there).

Answer (score 5):

There are several explanations, depending on a lot of factors.

At night, the air near the ground can have a different temperature than air only a few hundred feet above<sup>1</sup>. This affects the transmission of sound waves.

There is often less wind at night. If the wind is blowing towards the train it can be harder to hear

There is usually less ambient noise after dark, so the distant train sounds louder.

As pointed out elsewhere, maybe the trains don't use the horn in daytime.

1. I taught skydiving for 10 years. I can conclusively state that it is possible to have a *substantial* temperature differential, in both directions, between the ground and 3000 feet above the ground.

Comment: The lapse rate is often of order 1 degree per 100m. But usually in the wrong direction to cause the phenomenon described.

Comment: That's the standard adiabatic lapse rate. I'm talking sudden transitions, like "pleasant at 2000 feet, f**ing cold on the ground. Or the other way.

Answer (score 5):

It might not have to do with day/night physics at all.  It is possible that the train doesn't run during the day so it is unlikely you would even hear the horn.

I live in a city, about 2.5 miles from the rails, where during the day the train tracks are used only for public light rail transit.  The large locomotives only run at night after the light rail transit has stopped and therefore I only hear their horns at night.

Comment: The same thing happens some places even when the tracks aren't needed during the day for public transit; running trains at night avoids needing to hold up as much traffic at crossing.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think it has anything to do with quiteness, a typical surburban area, the noise difference during day and night ain't that great to mask train horn (which is pretty loud). It's the air temperature at work.

In the daytime the ground air is warm, bends airwaves upwards so for certain distance, you ain't gonna hear any sound at all, but during the night, the wave bends downward, bounced off ground and then bends downward again, I can even hear train rumbling at 8km away during night, and I live in rural which means the day&night noise difference ain't that high, but in the day time, there's nothing I can hear