# Are sounds louder at night, in the winter?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life

Surface temperatures of -40C and +40C are not unheard of in habitable areas on Earth. That's a variation of over 30% in density (for a given barometric pressure).

Does that mean that for the same event (dropping something) or the same setting on a volume control, the sound level one hears can vary by 30% over this temperature range?

Comment: Related/dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133198/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52269/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264349/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128144/25301, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I always hear remote train horn at night?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133198/)

Comment: @KyleKanos I'll go with the train horn at night. Thanks! ;-)